# Determine parameter E, B and learning rate value

Tags: machine-learning

Please can anyone tell me how to choose or fix these parameters :E (numb_epoch), B (batch_size) and local learning rate, to train model with image dataset?

How can we determine these parameters?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Batch is just as No. of image process on single instant through model ,you can choose any value for batch size but always less than total no images in dataset

Generally batch uses are {8,16,24,32,64} it totally depend upon you

for epochs i recommend you max no value where model start to overwite generally it's value is
 (Total No of Images)/batch size,but it not fixed you have find by manually and stop where your model start overwite or their is much diff between validation accuracy and training accuracy